# Text processing in bash

Tags: text-processing

I have two files: one which is the dictionary, and the other one corresponds to the list of words that appear in a transcription. I need to output the words out of vocabulary words. This is:

```
dict.txt
you 
she
apple
banana
strawberry
eat

transcript.txt
you
strawberry
and 
banana
<silence>
for 
breakfast
```

So, my desired output would look like this:

```
and
for
breakfast
<silence>
```

Is there any command output such words that are not found in the dictionary? thanks in advance!

Comment: aspell is one...

Comment: What about `<silence>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep -vf dict.txt transcript.txt
    and
    <silence>
    for
    breakfast
```

### fix

The above solution treats the file content as patterns. That does work in this example but not in general. In order to match the full lines literally you need:

```
grep -vFxf dict.txt transcript.txt
```

Comment: When I run that command I got "killed" :/

Comment: @little_mice: Where is killed coming from?  Is it an error or a word in one of your files?

Comment: When I run that command in the terminal it outputs "killed" in the same terminal. And the file where the output should be redirect is empty

Comment: This command must be run in the directory containing `dict.txt` and `transcript.txt` (or specify the full path to those files. Also this command as is will not produce an output file (because you have not asked for one), it will send the output to stdout.

Comment: it finally worked! the problem was that it wasn't run in the directory was @Jesse_b said. Thanks!

Comment: i'm looking for similar script, if i put word patterns in `dict.txt` instead of actual word, will it work?

Comment: @jerry It is even worse. It does not only work, that would even be considered an error in my original answer. In order to match literal words you need `grep -Fxf`.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, thanks, i tested from my end, `grep -vf` does read dict.txt as pattern, and it works for me